# How to set php ini settings in nginx config for just one host

Tags: php, nginx, config

One can set `error_reporting` in `nginx.conf` like so:

```
fastcgi_param   PHP_VALUE   error_reporting=E_ALL;
```

But if I do this in one server block, will it affect all the others as well? Should I change php settings in all server blocks simultaneously?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If every host on your server runs in its own PHP-FPM pool, than adding `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE ...` to one nginx host will not affect the other ones.

If on the other hand all `nginx` hosts use one PHP-FPM pool, you should specify `PHP_VALUE` for every host you have (`error_reporting=E_ALL` for one of them, empty value for others). Since `fastcgi_param` passes `PHP_VALUE` if specified, and doesn't pass if not. In a while all workers will have `PHP_VALUE=error_reporting=E_ALL`, unless you explicitly set `PHP_VALUE` in other hosts.

Additionally, `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE ...` declarations override one another (the last one takes effect).

Steps to reproduce:

1. `apt install nginx php5-fpm`
2. `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/hosts.conf`:

   ```
   server {
       server_name  s1;
       root  /srv/www/s1;
       location = / {
           include  fastcgi.conf;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  error_reporting=E_ERROR;
       }
   }

   server {
       server_name  s2;
       root  /srv/www/s1;
       location = / {
           include  fastcgi.conf;
           fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add `s1`, `s2` to `/etc/hosts`
4. Change `pm` to `static`, `pm.max_children` to `1` in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`
5. `cat /srv/www/s1/index.php`:

   ```
   <?php var_dump(error_reporting());
   ```
6. `systemctl restart php5-fpm && systemctl restart nginx`
7. `curl s2 && curl s1 && curl s2`

   ```
   int(22527)
   int(1)
   int(1)
   ```

Comment: It is not correct to state that between two server blocks one ```fastcgi_param``` will affect the other. It depends on the setup. In fact, the most common type of setup uses different PHP-FPM pools for each server block (different websites) and ```fastcgi_param``` between those will not affect one another (of course).

Comment: How do you know several pools are the most common? I believe, the most common setup is what comes by default. By default, `php-fpm` comes with one pool. People usually stick with defaults, unless they have reasons not to. But good point about it being not an issue between pools.

Comment: Try to think more in line of "people mostly use panels" (to my regret also). It's common - as in Plesk, where a separate PHP-FPM pool is created for each domain. This is also *common* security practice to isolate website users.

Comment: It seems like my nginx doesn't load any .ini file for php, how do I set this up? If I want to use the default development ini for example inside docker

Comment: @OZZIE This seems off-topic. If need be it's best to continue in a [chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233551/259354). From what I can see the official image sticks to the defaults. If you want to override some particular settings, one way would be `docker run ... -v ./my-overrides.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/my-overrides.ini ...`. Or use the [`volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) section in `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 16):

You can set `PHP_VALUE` per server and this will affect that server only.
If you need equal `PHP_VALUE` for all your servers with PHP, use include files.

For example (debian), create `/etc/nginx/conf.d/php_settings.cnf`:

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize=5M;\n error_reporting=E_ALL;";
```

Then include this file into any server or location config you need:

```
server {
  ...
  location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/php_settings.cnf;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Wrong, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32104484/52499). `php-fpm` maintains pool of `php` worker processes, which aren't restarted on each request. That's the point of FastCGI.